# Connecting copper and aluminium wires though a board

Tags: pcb, headphones, rca

My g430 headphones recently broke and I narrowed it down to the wire that connects the left speaker to the right. The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVXyveluhqU) I was watching recommends using a spare RCA cable to replace the wire, my only problem is that every wire in the headphones is aluminum but the RCA I took apart is copper. I understand that connecting them directly would be stupid but the connection would be going through the little PCB (image) they have in the headphones. Would this still be safe and durable? I don't know much if anything about electronics I just have a soldering iron and youtube.

[image: image of the board with the RCA cable in my hand]

Comment: How have you concluded they are aluminum? They are most likely just tinned copper.

Comment: Are you sure the wire is aluminum?  Usually it's an some nickle alloy over copper.

Comment: Ah good point, how would I check that?

Comment: @justing because copper is expensive and companies are cutting cost everywhere. Aluminum and Copper clad aluminum is getting more common.

Comment: Aluminium is less ductile and known to fatigue fracture. In wiring that flexes a lot, it would be a very poor choice.